# Partition Size Limit for BootCamp for new Mac Pro Machine?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I'm looking at an 8TB Mac Pro machine for business. I have found 4 year old articles stating there is a 2.2tb size limit on Boot Camp.

There is no current data.

Called and spoke with a senior advisor who could find no documentation. Was told to just buy and try it or reach out to the community....

Has anyone put more than 2.2tb on the windows side of a machine with a larger hard drive?

Will be running windows10.

Answer (score 1):

Mac Pro models introduced in 2013 or later do not have a 2.2 TB size limit for 64 bit Windows 10. If there is a limitation with respect to using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10, then Windows 10 could be installed without the use of the Boot Camp Assistant. Although, you would still want to use the Boot Camp Assistant to download Windows Support Software (i.e. the Windows drivers).

Windows runs on a Mac the same as any PC. Boot Camp refers to several entities, such as:

- There is a Boot Camp Assistant application which can download the Windows Support Software and simplify the installation of Windows.
- There is the Boot Camp installer, which installs the Windows Support Software.
- There is Boot Camp software installed in Windows that can configure hardware and set the default operating system to boot.
- The volume (partition) where Windows is installed is given the label `BOOTCAMP` and thus is referred to as Boot Camp in the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it had to do with block sizes and what the Apple Disk Utility could do formatting the bootcamp partition using exFAT.

If you are at all concerned, create a 2Tb partition while doing the install and then use a partitioning utility to change its size and modify the file system before restoring files and installing apps. Tools like Acronis, etc. should allow you to do this.